# Unable to delete Docker images associated with stopped containers using Python script

Tags: python, docker, image, docker-compose, containers

I'm working on a Python script to manage Docker containers using Docker Compose. The script starts and stops containers based on a given Docker Compose file. However, I'm having trouble deleting the Docker images associated with the stopped containers. All the files are in the same directory. Here are the details of my setup:

`Dockerfile`:
Here's the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

`docker-compose.yaml`:
Here's the content of my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

`app.py`:
Here's the content of my app.py Flask application:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

`docker_operations.py`:
I have a Python script docker_operations.py that I'm using to start and stop the Docker containers. Here's the content of that file:

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

def stop_and_remove_container_from_compose(compose_file):
    try:
        subprocess.run(["docker-compose", "-f", compose_file, "down"], check=True)
        print(f"Containers stopped and removed successfully using Docker Compose: {compose_file}")
        subprocess.run(["docker-compose", "-f", compose_file, "rm", "-fsv"], check=True)
        print(f"Docker Compose services removed successfully: {compose_file}")

        # Delete associated Docker images
        containers = subprocess.check_output(["docker", "ps", "-aq", "--filter", f"name={compose_file.stem}", "--format", "{{.Image}}"]).decode().splitlines()
        for container in containers:
            image_id = subprocess.check_output(["docker", "inspect", "-f", "{{.Image}}", container]).decode().strip()
            subprocess.run(["docker", "image", "rm", image_id], check=True)
        print("Docker images deleted successfully")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while stopping or removing the containers using Docker Compose: {e}")

# Example usage
compose_file = Path("docker-compose.yaml")  # Replace with the path to your Docker Compose file

stop_and_remove_container_from_compose(compose_file)
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I execute the stop_and_remove_container_from_compose function in docker_operations.py, the containers are stopped and removed successfully using Docker Compose. However, the associated Docker images are not being deleted. I have tried using the docker image rm command with the container IDs, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm retrieving and deleting the Docker images? How can I ensure that the images associated with the stopped containers are properly deleted?

Comment: I'd guess that, since `docker-compose down` deletes the containers, the `docker ps -aq` line doesn't find any containers.  Does the `for conatiner in containers` loop actually run at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker image rm` command is used to remove the docker images with image id, not with container id.

You can use `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml images` to list images used by the created containers with the docker-compose file. And can use `--quiet , -q` only to display IDs

here is the updated script

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

def stop_and_remove_container_from_compose(compose_file):
    try:
        # this should run first, as this list images used by the created containers
        images = subprocess.check_output(["docker-compose", "-f", compose_file, "images","-q"]).decode().splitlines()

        subprocess.run(["docker-compose", "-f", compose_file, "down"], check=True)
        print(f"Containers stopped and removed successfully using Docker Compose: {compose_file}")
        
        subprocess.run(["docker-compose", "-f", compose_file, "rm", "-fsv"], check=True)
        print(f"Docker Compose services removed successfully: {compose_file}")

        # removing the images
        for image in images:
            subprocess.run(["docker", "image", "rm", image], check=True)

        print("Docker images deleted successfully")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while stopping or removing the containers using Docker Compose: {e}")

compose_file = Path("docker-compose.yaml") 
stop_and_remove_container_from_compose(compose_file)
```